# JWS & Secure Database Connections using Glassfish V3

Tags: java, swing, jndi, glassfish-3, java-web-start

I need to distribute my Swing application using JWS. I use JPA and connect to both Postgres and MSSQL.

How do I ensure secure database connections? Can I use JDBC Connection Pooling configured in Glassfish? If so, how do I configure my app to use it?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ensure secure database connections? Can I use JDBC Connection Pooling configured in Glassfish? If so, how do I configure my app to use it?

In a typical N-tier architecture, the Swing client would connect to services running at the app server level (via EJBs or Web Services)  and those services would access to the database via JDBC.

Both the database and the application server(s) would be installed in a DMZ (or even separate DMZ) and connections to the database would be only allowed from the application server (via a connection pool but this is kinda a detail).

And depending on your environment (i.e. if clients are communicating over a trusted network  or not), you'd have to use encryption to secure the communications between the clients and the server.